# Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: INVALID]

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, error

I was using Web3.py to send Tether from address A to B:

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/REDACTED'))
teth = '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7'

# begin_target_details
target = '0x0266326C0a57B1EcC680eC2B9d7A0da3f96E61f1'
priv_key_target = 'REDACTED'
# end_target_details

# begin_win_details
win = '0xFf3098Bc586538C47D5eb747405f8d9fdd165b3d'
win_priv_key = 'REDACTED'
# end_win_details

nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(target)

teth_abi = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_upgradedAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"deprecate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"deprecated","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_evilUser","type":"address"}],"name":"addBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradedAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balances","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"maximumFee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_maker","type":"address"}],"name":"getBlackListStatus","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newMaxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setParams","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"issue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"redeem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"basisPointsRate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"isBlackListed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_clearedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"removeBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_UINT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"destroyBlackFunds","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Issue","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Redeem","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"Deprecate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"feeBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"maxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Params","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_balance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DestroyedBlackFunds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"AddedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"RemovedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"}]'

nonce_target = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(target)
contract = w3.eth.contract(teth, abi = teth_abi)

#tether_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(target).call()

transact_details = {
  'nonce': nonce,
  'gas': 100000,
  'gasPrice': w3.toWei(13, 'gwei')
}

ransact1 = contract.functions.transfer(win, w3.toWei(2, 'ether')).buildTransaction(transact_details)
sign_transact1 = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transact1, priv_key_target)
txhash1 = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(sign_transact1.rawTransaction)

# print txhash of USDT transact
#print('[+] TXID: ' + w3.toHex(txhash1))
```

After I test it, transfer fails without any further information, only showing this error: **Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: INVALID]**

You can see it on etherscan: Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: INVALID]

You can see it in here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9a22e11928ad1c8b94cc65f48aa2613d273b52ff2dcf0781d9c9f40c40fa827a

What am I doing wrong; I didn't find any helpful solution for that. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error, thanks for the dude in Discord.

Problem: I was using wrong value in `toWei()` function;
I needed to use 'mwei' (which is equal to tether token value)

After that, it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an ERC-20 token transfer might have failed error, the amount/token the sender sent does not leave the sender address but the “Gas Fee” is deducted.

The main reasons are on the contract & token failure nature. Below are the most common reasons why an ERC-20 token transfer might have failed:

The Token contract is locked or paused (tokens are not transferable yet).The variables include: minting, mintingFinished, paused, transferable, transferableStartTime, paused, locked
The sending From address has an insufficient token balance. Please ensure that the sending address has enough balance of the transferring token before sending token to another address
Token contract does not emit a Transfer event even though the balance is actually deducted (Not fully ERC-20 Compliant). The token contract of a specific token does not provide a valid transfer event log thus causing the transaction to fail. This issue is due to the compliance policy toward ERC-20 tokens.

Comment: Yeah, okay thanks; but I did like exactly in YouTube videos; the problem is transaction is working as expected when use MetaMask; but it's not working when I use the code. Wallet had enough eth to transfer ERC-20 tokens.

Comment: I even used web3.js but hell nah... I don't even know what's the problem... I think contract is working well

Comment: can you help me with that, I would be very thankful and appreciate your time man

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am facing the same problem while using metamask. I am not able to transfer usdt erc20 tokens and I have more than enough funds to carry out the task. I have tried to increase the gwei a couple of times but every time the transaction fails and my ether is deducted and it says error encountered during contract execution. (Exexution reverted)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/88790)